# Why is Selecting From Table Variable Far Slower than List of Integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a pretty big MSSQL stored procedure that I need to conditionally check for certain IDs:

```
Select SomeColumns
From BigTable b
Join LotsOfTables l on b.LongStringField = l.LongStringField
Where b.SomeID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I wanted to conditionally check the SomeID field, so I did the following:

```
if @enteredText = 'This'
INSERT INTO @AwesomeIDs
VALUES(1),(2),(3)

if @enteredText = 'That'
INSERT INTO @AwesomeIDs
VALUES(4),(5)

Select SomeColumns
From BigTable b
Join LotsOfTables l on b.LongStringField = l.LongStringField
Where b.SomeID in (Select ID from @AwesomeIDs)
```

Nothing else has changed, yet I can't even get the latter query to grab 5 records. The top query returns 5000 records in less than 3 seconds.  Why is selecting from a table variable so much drastically slower?

Comment: `where x in (1,2,3,4,5)` is probably executed as `where x=1 or x=2 or x=3 or x=4 or x=5`, whereas `in (select id from @table)` is a join, albeit on a table variable (not a #temp table btw).. Compare the execution plans; that should give you a hint.

Comment: Good point on it not being a temp table, I've been back and fourth so many times but yes, table variable.

Comment: Can you post an image of your execution plan?

Comment: You might try declaring a PRIMARY KEY constraint on the table variable column.  That will at least give the optimizer knowledge of cardinality, which might improve the plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two other possible options you can consider

### Option 1

```
Select SomeColumns
From BigTable b
Join LotsOfTables l on b.LongStringField = l.LongStringField
Where 
     ( b.SomeID IN (1,2,3) AND @enteredText = 'This')
 OR 
     ( b.SomeID IN (4,5)   AND @enteredText = 'That')
```

### Option 2

```
Select SomeColumns
From BigTable b
Join LotsOfTables l on b.LongStringField = l.LongStringField
Where EXISTS (Select 1
             from @AwesomeIDs
             WHERE b.SomeID = ID)
```

Mind you for Table variables , SQL Server always assumes there is only ONE row in the table (except sql 2014 , assumption is 100 rows) and it can affect the estimated and actual plans. But 1 row against 3 not really a deal breaker.